# "An Arabic-poems-based video"; is the adj. correct?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

I want to refer to the fact that most of a video’s content is Arabic poems. Is it correct to write: an Arabic-poems-based video? Or should it be an Arabic-poetry-based video, for example? Or is the idea of forming the adj. this way entirely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Although a concatenation of nouns is grammatical, it is not the idiomatic choice here.   You'd want to put the information about the Arabic poems in a relative clause:

It is a video *based on Arabic poems*.